# Resize UserControl hosted in a Window with it's parent after initialization

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a Window to host several different usercontrols as a dialog. The window basically looks like this:

```
 <Window x:Class="GenericWindow"
        x:Name="BaseDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=wpfDialogs:DialogViewModel, 
IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="{Binding Title}"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        MinWidth="400" MinHeight="400"
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Margin="10 10 10 0" Content="{Binding}"/>

 </Window>
```

My UserControl looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PickControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm"
    xmlns:dxprg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/propertygrid"        
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"        
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="mainWindow">

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height ="600" MinHeight="200"/>
      <RowDefinition Height ="15"/>
      <RowDefinition Height ="400" MinHeight="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width ="700"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


<-- content goes here -->
</UserControl>
```

On startup my Dialog has the size of the grid in the hosted usercontrol. Thats fine. But when resizing the outer window, the grid inside the usercontrol will remain the same static set size. I want the outer window to have the size of the content at initilization and after that the content to resize with the outer window. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: remove the height and widths from row and column definitions.

Comment: or use height/width in terms of '*'

Comment: @AthulRaj but then the size at initialization wont be the desired

Comment: set the desired height/width for the window. not the usercontrol

Answer (score 0):

1. Get rid of the `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` from the defintion of the `UserControl` if you don't always want it to have a fixed size.
2. Set its initial size in the window and then handle the `SizeChanged` event twice:

   ```
    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SizeChanged -= Window_SizeChanged;
        SizeChanged += RemoveInitialSizeConstraints;
    }

    private void RemoveInitialSizeConstraints(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        cc.Height = double.NaN;
        cc.Width = double.NaN;
        SizeChanged -= RemoveInitialSizeConstraints;
    }
   ```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="GenericWindow"
        x:Name="BaseDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=wpfDialogs:DialogViewModel, 
IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="{Binding Title}"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        MinWidth="400" MinHeight="400"
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentPresenter x:Name="cc" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10 10 10 0" Content="{Binding}"
                      Height ="600" MinHeight="200" Width="700"/>

</Window>
```

Comment: thanks :) The initial size can be set like this, but the usercontrol wont resize when the window is resized. It will stay at initial width/height values, even if the window is maximized to fullscreen.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Does the `Window_SizeChanged` and `RemoveInitialSizeConstraints` really get called when you debug the code? They set the `Width` and `Height` properties to `double.Nan` which means that the `UserControl` doesn't have a fixed size any more. Unless you set its size somewhere else in your code...

Comment: Instead of double.NaN, I set the Height/Width to the desired initial size there. If I set it to NaN, where will it get the initial size from?

Comment: @user3292642: Oh, the intial size should be set in the XAML. I somehow managed to miss to include this in my sample markup. See my edit where the initial size is set in the `ContentPresenter` element in the XAML.